# How to use jQuery to display the real images when I click on the temporary images at 480px screenwide?

Tags: jquery

I have created a responsive web site which contains some images. I need these images to be replaced by temporary images when the website displays at 480 pixel screen wide or less.

Then if the user likes to see the image, he or she just clicks on the temporary image in order to show the real one.

How could I do that by using jquery?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://try.jquery.com

Comment: you should post some code to show what you've tried.This is a help forum not a Q&A forum

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this one? I did a DEMO here http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/wtFXD/

First, resize the result panel wider than 480px, then see, no temp image is shown.

Then, resize the result panel smaller than 480px, you can see temp image, click and see big image.

## HTML

```
<img class="thumb" src="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/thumbs/wind_capture-t1.jpg" width="270" height="169" title="Click to enlarge." target="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/wind_capture-wide.jpg" />

<img class="thumb" src="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/thumbs/hamann_range_rover_vogue_2013_widebody_mystere-t1.jpg" width="270" height="169" title="Click to enlarge." target="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/hamann_range_rover_vogue_2013_widebody_mystere-wide.jpg" />
```

## CSS

```
.thumb {
    float:left;
    display:none;
    padding:1px;
    border:1px solid #dfdfdf;    
}
.big{
    float:left;
    width:480px;
    height:300px;
    padding:1px;
    border:1px solid #dfdfdf; 
}
```

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(document).width() <= 480){
        $(".thumb").show();
        $(".thumb").click(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('thumb').addClass('big');
            $(this).attr("src").replace($(this).attr('target'));
        });
    }
});
```